# React state getting state's value

Tags: reactjs, state

The subject may be a bit misleading, please see code below.

```
this.state = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: this.state.a + this.state.b
}
```

I did think of using componentDidMount() but it run only once.

componentWillUpdate() & componentDidUpdate() could get the values of nextState / prevState, but just not the current state.

So, would you please suggest what approach should I take?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you cant change state like that in state object, and that's bad , using setState  you can change the react state

Comment: You already have values of `a` and `b`, you can directly set value of c. You do not need (and should not) to reference `a` and `b` to set `c`.

On subsequent renders of the component you should use `setState` to set the state of the component.

You might want to read this : https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly